# query without union pivot select

Tags: sql, oracle10g

hello i have query as below
this execution time is to long.
please introduced me to try a different solution
.there is my query(oracle 10g)

```
SELECT *
  FROM (WITH T AS (SELECT COR_ID, COR_COD, WEI1, DAYS, 'WEI1' WEI_TYPE
                     FROM (TABLE))
         SELECT *
           FROM T PIVOT(MAX(WEI1) FOR(DAYS) IN('01' DAY_01,
                                               '02' DAY_02,
                                               '03' DAY_03,
                                               '04' DAY_04,
                                               '05' DAY_05,
                                               '06' DAY_06,
                                               '07' DAY_07,
                                               '08' DAY_08)))
UNION
  FROM (WITH T AS (SELECT COR_ID, COR_COD, WEI2, DAYS, 'WEI2' WEI_TYPE
                     FROM (TABLE))
         SELECT *
           FROM T PIVOT(MAX(WEI2) FOR(DAYS) IN('01' DAY_01,
                                               '02' DAY_02,
                                               '03' DAY_03,
                                               '04' DAY_04,
                                               '05' DAY_05,
                                               '06' DAY_06,
                                               '07' DAY_07,
                                               '08' DAY_08)))
UNION
  FROM (WITH T AS (SELECT COR_ID, COR_COD, WEI3, DAYS, 'WEI3' WEI_TYPE
                     FROM (TABLE))
         SELECT *
           FROM T PIVOT(MAX(WEI3) FOR(DAYS) IN('01' DAY_01,
                                               '02' DAY_02,
                                               '03' DAY_03,
                                               '04' DAY_04,
                                               '05' DAY_05,
                                               '06' DAY_06,
                                               '07' DAY_07,
                                               '08' DAY_08)))
```

how change this query to without union ?

   **that result from this**:
[that result from this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nkAkP.jpg)

**to this:**
[to this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0d29.jpg)
 
please help me

Answer (score 0):

You have a table with several wei columns and separate rows for the days. And you want a result with several day columns and separate rows for the weis instead. So this is a transformation with rows to columns *and* columns to rows.

Your query looks appropriate for this task. Only, you are using `UNION` where it should be `UNION ALL`. `UNION ALL` glues the records together, which is what you want. `UNION` does the same but also looks for duplicates to remove. Your three partial queries don't produce duplicates however - they differ at least in the `wei_type`. Change `UNION` to `UNION ALL`, so the DBMS doesn't have to do that extra work, which should result in a slightly faster query.

And here is an alternative query neither using `UNION` nor `UNION ALL` on your table. It cross joins with weis to produce these rows and then aggregates/pivots to get from day rows to columns.

```
select 
  cor_id, cor_cod, wei_type, day_01, day_02, day_03, day_04, day_05, day_06, day_07, day_08
from
(
  select
    t.cor_id, t.cor_cod, t.days, w.wei_type,
    case w.wei_type when 'WEI1' then t.wei1 when 'WEI2' then t.wei2 else t.wei3 end as wei
  from thetable t
  cross join 
  (
    select 'WEI1' as wei_type from dual
    union all
    select 'WEI2' as wei_type from dual
    union all
    select 'WEI3' as wei_type from dual
  ) w
)
pivot 
(
   max(wei) for(days) in 
   (
     '01' day_01, '02' day_02, '03' day_03, '04' day_04,
     '05' day_05, '06' day_06, '07' day_07, '08' day_08
   )
)
order by cor_id, cor_cod, wei_type;
```

And here is the same with conditional aggregation instead of `PIVOT` which does exactly the same.

```
select 
  cor_id, cor_cod, wei_type,
  max(case when days = '01' then wei end) as day_01,
  max(case when days = '02' then wei end) as day_02,
  max(case when days = '03' then wei end) as day_03,
  max(case when days = '04' then wei end) as day_04,
  max(case when days = '05' then wei end) as day_05,
  max(case when days = '06' then wei end) as day_06,
  max(case when days = '07' then wei end) as day_07,
  max(case when days = '08' then wei end) as day_08
from
(
  select
    t.cor_id, t.cor_cod, t.days, w.wei_type,
    case w.wei_type when 'WEI1' then t.wei1 when 'WEI2' then t.wei2 else t.wei3 end as wei
  from thetable t
  cross join 
  (
    select 'WEI1' as wei_type from dual
    union all
    select 'WEI2' as wei_type from dual
    union all
    select 'WEI3' as wei_type from dual
  ) w
)
group by cor_id, cor_cod, wei_type
order by cor_id, cor_cod, wei_type;
```